# Insert to SqlLite database using EF always return 1 for Id

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I have a simple contact app that uses sqllite as database. I use EF code first to design it's database. When I save the data, It's Id produces in database as expected (Auto Increment), but the **SaveChanges** method always return 1 for Id.

How can I get the latest table Id?

DbContext :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        string dbPath = DbPathGenerator.GetDbPath();

        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={dbPath}/LiteContactsDb.db");
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany<Address>()
            .WithOne(a => a.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany<Phone>()
            .WithOne(a => a.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PersonId);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Save Method :

```
    public bool SaveContact(PersonViewModel personViewModel, PhoneViewModel phoneViewModel, AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            Person person = new Person();

            person.FirstName = personViewModel.FirstName;
            person.LastName = personViewModel.LastName;
            person.Email = personViewModel.Email;

            _context.Persons.Add(person);
            var personId = _context.SaveChanges();

            Phone phone = new Phone();

            phone.PersonId = personId;
            phone.PhoneTitle = phoneViewModel.PhoneTitle;
            phone.PhoneNumber = phoneViewModel.PhoneNumber;

            Address address = new Address();

            address.PersonId = personId;
            address.AddressTitle = addressViewModel.AddressTitle;
            address.AddressString = addressViewModel.AddressString;
            address.PostalCode = addressViewModel.PostalCode;

            _context.Phones.Add(phone);
            _context.Addresses.Add(address);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**_context.SaveChanges();** always returns 1.

Thanks

Comment: SaveChanges returns the affected row count, not the Id. Id should be reflected on the entity itself.

Comment: The code is wrong. `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes and sets the IDs for *all* new objects. Just create the objects and assign them to properties as needed, then *only call .Add(person)*. EF will insert *all* the related entities

Comment: In fact, calling `SaveChanges` multiple times is a code bug. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work. It tracks all changes made during its lifetime. If you dispose it, the changes are lost. `SaveChanges` should only be called at the last moment to persist *all* pending changes in a single internal transaction. This way, even if an error occurs the changes will be "rolled back"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`SaveChanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-savechanges) is not the id of the newly created record, but the number of changes. So if you insert a single item, the return value will always be 1.

If you want to access the id of the newly inserted object, check out the id-property of the object. It is updated after the insert.

Answer (score 1):

First, `SaveChanges` returns the number of affected rows, not any IDs generated when storing objects. Second, `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes, not just a single object.

DbContext is a disconnected Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It doesn't even keep a connection open until it has to either load data or save the changes. `SaveChanges` is called to persist *all* changes, not just the latest. When that happens a new connection opens and all changes are persisted in a single internal transaction.

This means that rolling back the Unit of Work needs no extra effort - just don't call `SaveChanges` before disposing the DbContext.

Finally, there's no need to add objects individually. Calling `.Add(person)` will add all objects accessible through it in the `Added` state. When the changes are peristed DbContext will execute the INSERT operations in the correct order and fix up the FK properties automatically.

This means that adding a person, phone and address in a single consistent "transaction" only needs this :

```
var person = new Person {
    FirstName = personViewModel.FirstName,
    LastName = personViewModel.LastName,
    Email = personViewModel.Email
   
    Phone = new Phone {
        PhoneTitle = phoneViewModel.PhoneTitle,
        PhoneNumber = phoneViewModel.PhoneNumber
    },
    
    Address = new Address {
        AddressTitle = addressViewModel.AddressTitle,
        AddressString = addressViewModel.AddressString,
        PostalCode = addressViewModel.PostalCode
     }
}
_context.Persons.Add(person);

...
_context.SaveChanges();
```